# "Can't add a reference to the specified file.", when trying to update VBAProject reference mscorlib.dll version

Tags: excel, vba, reference, mscorlib

Got new computer and I am unable to get my previously made Excel VBA macros work.
Problem lies in mscorlib.dll, what I can't update from v2.0.50727 to v4.0.30319.
Message "Can't add a reference to the specified file." shows up even if I try to browse and choose the file it is already using.

I tried to run excel as administrator and tried to change location for the .dll

Comment: Try downloading the .net Framework and installing it. Then may have to refresh the references in your Excel spreadsheet manually by deleting  and readding the  mscorlib.tlb reference.  If using [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) it's a bit easier to add/remove references. 
 Eg location \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb

Comment: Not sure if it's related but It needs the particular [.NetFamework v 3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website) to work (you can have multiple versions installed). Unfortunately, its intelli sense still doesn't work. The location of its installation on Windows 10 is in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` (to check if you have it installed).